# Amchart and Ajax getting data in incorrect format

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, format, amcharts

I want to use AmChart and getting data for charts from php.

here is my php file:

```
$colors = Array("#FF0F00","#FF6600","#FF9E01","#FCD202","#F8FF01","#B0DE09","#04D215","#0D8ECF","#0D52D1","#2A0CD0","#8A0CCF","#CD0D74","#754DEB","#DDDDDD","#999999","#333333","#000000");

$datas = $bdd->query("SELECT count(*) as count, rest.name as name
                   FROM command com, zone z, dinningroom dr, restaurant rest
                   WHERE com.zone = z.number
                       AND z.dinningroom = dr.number
                       AND dr.restaurant = rest.number
                   GROUP BY rest.number;");

$i=0;
while($data = $datas->fetch())
{   
    $dataList[$i]=array("name"=>$data['name'],"count"=>$data['count'],"color"=>$colors[$i]);
    $i++;
}
echo json_encode($dataList);
?>
```

$datas has good data. SQL request is good and return what i want.

Here is my javascript with my Ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
              url: 'statComPerMenu.php',
              failure: function (data) {
                  alert('fail: ' + data);
              },
              success: function(data) {
                    var statComPerMenuChart;

                    // SERIAL CHART
                    statComPerMenuChart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
                    statComPerMenuChart.dataProvider = data;

                    statComPerMenuChart.categoryField = "name";
                    // the following two lines makes chart 3D
                    statComPerMenuChart.depth3D = 20;
                    statComPerMenuChart.angle = 30;

                    // AXES
                    // category
                    var categoryAxis = statComPerMenuChart.categoryAxis;
                    categoryAxis.labelRotation = 90;
                    categoryAxis.dashLength = 5;
                    categoryAxis.gridPosition = "start";

                    // value
                    var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis;
                    valueAxis.dashLength = 5;
                    statComPerMenuChart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);

                    // GRAPH            
                    var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
                    graph.valueField = "count";
                    graph.colorField = "color";
                    graph.balloonText = "[[name]]: [[count]]";
                    graph.type = "column";
                    graph.lineAlpha = 0;
                    graph.fillAlphas = 1;
                    statComPerMenuChart.addGraph(graph);

                    // WRITE
                    statComPerMenuChart.write("chartdiv");

           } //Success
           });
       };
```

No chart are displayed.

But if I change the var 'data' by this:
    data = [{name: "toto", count: 10, color: "#FF0F00"},{name: "toto", count: 10, color: "#FF0F00"}];
in success from Ajax query, this works correctly! I get the chart...

So the problem stay is the format i get from my php file... i can't find the right format to return.

EDIT:
if i do:

```
success: function(data) {
    $("#omg").html(data);
    [...]
    chart.dataProvider = data;
    [...]
}
```

this is printed on page:
[{"name":"Brussels","count":"4","color":"#FF0F00"},{"name":"Chimay","count":"2","color":"#FF6600"}]
and shows an empty chart.

if copy paste printed table as data:

```
success: function(data) {
    $("#omg").html(data);
    [...]
    chart.dataProvider =  [{"name":"Brussels","count":"4","color":"#FF0F00"},{"name":"Chimay","count":"2","color":"#FF6600"}];
    [...]
}
```

the chart is well displayed.

Comment: What are you actually asking here?  At the moment it seems like "help me debug my code", rather than asking a broader question which would benefit people searching for this.

Comment: have you try to format your data in json?  use 'json_encode()' in your array

Comment: I need a way to return my data. I also tried with JSON but doesn't work too :(

Comment: please give us the code that make the system work and we'll help you

Comment: It might seem like amCharts supports JSON data. However, it is actually not valid JSON.  I wrote this tutorial for Rails, but the section re: data formatting might help you: [amcharts tutorial](http://www.diasks2.com/post/21827658042/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-a-dynamic-amcharts-graph)

Comment: I have add some information above!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by doing this:

```
$.getJSON("statComPerMenu.php",  // le fichier qui recevra la requête
          null,  // les paramètres
          function(data){  // la fonction qui traitera l'objet reçu
          [...]
          chart.dataProvider = data;
          [...]
});
```

Check this for more about $.getJSON (french): http://www.hooba.ca/blog/2008/echange-dobjets-json-entre-php-et-javascript-facile-grace-a-jquery/